# Get file path from content URI

Tags: android, file, uri

I had this working at a time, but now it fails every time I try to get the file path. I am receiving the file from Acrobat Reader and can receive the file name and size, but not the relative file path.

My code looks like this:

```
if(uri.getScheme().equals("content"))
        {
            String[] dataFields = new String[]{
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                    OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    OpenableColumns.SIZE};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, dataFields, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        fileLocation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
        title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        size = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE));

        cursor.close();

        contentType = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    }
```

I get the following error in LogCat:

```
Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 2 columns.
```

I understand it as it can't find the column. However, I don't understand how this can be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). There is no requirement that the `Uri` be from `MediaStore` or otherwise have a `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` column. If you want to access the content represented by the `Uri`, use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: True... what I want is to get the file path without "content://" and the other folders, so that I later on can open the file in a File object.

Comment: @FireFly3000: "what I want is to get the file path" -- there is no file path. There is no requirement that the data behind the `Uri` be a file that you can access by any means. It might be in internal storage. It might be in removable storage. It might be encrypted. It might not even be a file, but rather streamed in real time off the Internet.